# NodeJS require scope variables

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a module like this.

somemodule.js

```
module.exports = {
  val: null,
  get: function() {
     finddata('/', function(resp) {
       this.val = resp
     }
  }
}
```

and is called like this:

```
var x = require('somemodule');
x.get();
x.get();
```

After the 1st get call, this x.val is not being set. Tried this as well which does not work:

```
module.exports = {
  val: null,
  get: function() {
     var that = this;
     finddata('/', function(resp) {
       that.val = resp
     }
  }
}
```

How do I set x.val?

Comment: Is `finddata` async? Are you sure its callback has been called?

Comment: It is async, and it is being called

Comment: The first snippet won't work as intended because `this` keyword in the callback means the function itself instead of the whole object you want to export. I don't see anything wrong with the second approach so how did you check if 'x.val' is set or not? Can you do `console.log(that)` to see if it is set?

Comment: *"Tried this as well which does not work"* That will work. The problem is that you don't know when the async operation finished, so you don't know when to look at `x.val`.

Comment: Could you share the relevant code for `finddata`?

Answer (score 2):

Your finddata is running asynchronously , it's getting called and returned back immediately to continue next line execution . That moment its not sure callback is executed or not . Once callback is executed then only value will be set . To make sure value is set and then after getting the value , you can use promises.

I have just taken two sample file a.js and b.js to explain how it works

**a.js**

```
module.exports = {
      val:null,
      get:function(){
          var that = this;
          return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
              that.finddata('/', function(resp){
                   that.val = resp;
                   resolve()
                 })
          });

      },
      finddata :function(path,callback){
          setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Lets wait for some time");
            callback(10);
          }, 100)
      }
    }
```

**b.js**

```
var x = require('./a');
 x.get().then(function(){
       console.log(x.val)
 });
```

**Output**

```
Lets wait for some time

10
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your solution so that others can learn. This would make your answer much more useful.

Comment: Thanks Felix , I am also learning from you@FelixKling

Answer (score 2):

First of all, problem is not about requiring something and it is not related to scope. What is actually happening is, as already stated by others, `finddata` is asynchronous function meaning that you don't know at what time in future callback `function (resp) {...}` will be invoked and when `val` be something other than `null`. To tackle this you need either to pass additional callback to `get` function, or to return a promise from `get` function. Cleaner approach would be to return Promise from `get` function.

```
x.get()
.then(() => {
  // val is ready
})
```

or

```
x.get(() => {
  // val is ready
})
```

Another problem that you have is that you are not taking into account what if `finddata` invokes your callback with an error? Having something like:

```
finddata('/', function(resp){
  that.val = resp
}
```

Is really something what you don't want to have. With code that you have, if `finddata` invokes your callback with an `error`, `val` would be equal to that error, otherwise it would be equal to `null`, if `finddata` complies to node best practices to invoke callback with `null` if there was no errors, such as `cb(null, data)`.

Besides that what you are trying to do? Is there a need for exposing module with `val` thing? Is `get` function meant to be called regularly from app? If so why introducing new module, just call `finddata` which is i guess module by itself already.